# hide my iconlabel

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

What I want to achieve is once a user have entered wrong data, an image label will be displayed.

Visible method is not recommended due to my `lblMessage` serve for other purposes as well.

My big big problem now is once users corrected their input field, the label message is disabled but the image still visible, just because i set my `lblMessage` to `null`.

Is there any method I can use like when there are something is `lblMessage` invoke image CSS but whenever there is nothing in `lblMessage,` no css is invoked?

```
if (!Utils.mtdIsBlank(Session["Message"]))
{
    lblMessage.Text = Session["Message"].ToString();
    Session["Message"] = null;
}
else
{
    lblMessage.Text = "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your problem is that you don't know how to add/remove styles to your asp.net controls: You can use CssClass for asp.net controls (label, panel,...) like this:

```
lbl.CssClass = "new-class";
```

For your example, something like this should work for you:

```
if (!Utils.mtdIsBlank(Session["Message"]))
{
    //If is not blank no image
    lblMessage.Text = Session["Message"].ToString();
    Session["Message"] = null;
    lblMessage.CssClass = "no-img";
}
else
{
    //Show alert image
    lblMessage.Text = "";
    //Replace with-img with the css class you are using
    lblMessage.CssClass = "with-img";
}
```

Then you need to add a css property:

```
.no-img{
   background: none;
   //Anything else
}
```